# Swift REPL custom class variable output

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop

I recently started using the Swift REPL to try out my own frameworks. What I noticed is that the output when defining a variable using one of my custom classes does not use the Printable protocol. Here's an example:

```
$ let vector = Vector([1, 2, 3])

> vector: MathEagle.Vector<Int> = {
    elements = 3 values {
      [0] = 1
      [1] = 2
      [2] = 3
    }
  }
```

So my Vector class is represented by it's internal variables. (Note that MathEagle is the name of the framework.)

Is there a way to change this output? Can I adopt a certain protocol or something?

Thanks

Comment: @MartinR That's too bad... Thanks for your answer!